# Provider from context value doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to learn ContextAPI in a new react+typescript sample project.

I want to manage locale / authentication.

I have to initialise my context values (required by Typescript / eslint), specially login/logout function, or an error occured in "App.tsx": "cannot invoke an object which is possible undefined".

Right, I tried to initialised my context as follow:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
    ...initialState,
    login: () => {
        throw new Error("login() not implemented yet");
    },
    logout: () => {
        throw new Error("logout() not implemented yet");
    }
 });
```

Problem now, when I define login/logout function and passed as value to my provider, my button throw the "login not implemented yet" error.

Here is my code:

```
// ./App.tsx
import React from "react";
import { NavItem, Button } from "reactstrap";

import * as Context from "./contexts";

const App = () => {
      return (
      <Context.Language.Consumer>
        {({ locale, translation, switchLocale }) => (
            <Context.Auth.Consumer>
              {Auth => (
                  <NavItem right>
                    {Auth.isLoggedIn ? (
                        <Button onClick={() => Auth.logout()}>
                          {translation.logout}
                        </Button>
                    ) : (
                        <Button onClick={() => Auth.login()}>
                          {translation.login}
                        </Button>
                    )}
                  </NavItem>
              )}
            </Context.Auth.Consumer>
        )}
      </Context.Language.Consumer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

--

```
// ./contexts/AuthContext.tsx
import React, {Component} from "react";

type ContextProps = {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

const initialState = { isLoggedIn: false };
type Props = {};
type State = {} & typeof initialState;

const AuthContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
  ...initialState,
  login: () => {
    throw new Error("login() not implemented yet");
  },
  logout: () => {
    throw new Error("logout() not implemented yet");
  }
});

class AuthProvider extends Component<Props, State> {
   readonly state = initialState;

  login = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: true
    });
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{...this.state, login: this.login, logout: this.logout}}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const Consumer = AuthContext.Consumer;
export const Provider = AuthProvider;
```

And finally:

```
// ./contexts/index.js
import * as Auth from "./AuthContext";
import * as Language from "./LanguageContext";

export { Auth, Language };
```

It seems that the new login/logout definition is not passed to the provider in AuthContext. I'm pretty certain that I miss a concept from ContextAPI and I didn't understand right the logic behind. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the provider with the new context. React will go up the tree to find the first context provider, if there ins't any, the consumer gets the default value.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
  <Context.Language.Consumer>
    {({ locale, translation, switchLocale }) => (
       <Context.Auth.Provider>
          <Context.Auth.Consumer>
            {Auth => (
                <NavItem right>
                  {Auth.isLoggedIn ? (
                      <Button onClick={() => Auth.logout()}>
                        {translation.logout}
                      </Button>
                  ) : (
                      <Button onClick={() => Auth.login()}>
                        {translation.login}
                      </Button>
                  )}
                </NavItem>
            )}
        </Context.Auth.Consumer>
      <Context.Auth.Provider>
    )}
  </Context.Language.Consumer>
```

);
};